# SQL Server Computed Column

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

In my database, I have a computed column based off of the ID field. Its formula is like so:

```
('Q'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],[EnquiryID],(0)),(6)))
```

This means it'll prepend 0's upto 6 digits long. For example if my ID was 5, it'll be Q000005. If its 100 it'll be Q000100.

I've noticed that my ID is already at 4000 after just a few weeks. So my computed column looks like Q004000.

My question is, once it gets to say Q999999. Will it start at 1 again or add another 0 automatically? So will it go back to Q000001 or will it be Q1000000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use our brain cells and logically analyze this:

- your `EnquiryID` value goes to 1'000'000 - so your `CONVERT(varchar, EnquiryID, 0)`  returns `1000000`
- next you prepend this with five zeroes, which gives you: `000001000000`
- now you take the six right-most characters of that, which are: `000000`
- and you prepend a `Q` giving you the result of `Q000000`

So I guess you better drop that computed column and re-create it with more digits! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest:

```
declare @EnquiryId as Int = 1000000
select ('Q'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],@EnquiryID,(0)),(6)))
```

Answer (score 1):

drop it as @marc_s said.

2 comments:

1) useful knowledge: computed columns are not stored on the DB (unless they are indexed) so you can drop and recreate it as you wish

2) (just a silly comment but it was the first thing that crossed my mind): do you really need to do it? Let's use our brain cells and logically analyze this also as @marc_s said:  4000 records "in a few weeks". Lets say "few" are 3, so you have an average of 1333 records per week. 999999/1333 =  750 weeks, that's 13 years. Aren't you a little worried over nothing? :)

Comment: The computed columns are not stored unless you add the `PERSISTED` keyword to the definition (and the computation is deterministic)